# Confusion in object ID when editing and deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Specify the ID of the desired object, while the first object of the model is always deleted/edited. For the first time I met such a problem, checked everything. What's wrong?

```
Started DELETE "/questions/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-05 10:48:13 +0300
Processing by QuestionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"luh7ShhQ9pWka7wmWMnG4WMQVAnKRjtAJwn0s5at8/GBDOtFjUwZEF70o8hOFOaAN+pVB592V1+egH/PDJVUVA==", "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/gorbunov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE (6) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:86
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:45
  Question Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ?  [["id", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:45
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:45
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questions
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

I want to delete an object with ID =6, but delete an object with ID = 3

Action **Destroy** in controller:

```
def destroy
   @question = Question.find_by(params[:id])
   @question.destroy
   flash[:success] = 'Вопрос успешно удалён!'
   redirect_to questions_path
  end
```

Link_to helper for delete object:

```
<%= link_to qest, class: 'btn btn-outline-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Хорошо подумал?"} do %>
```

Comment: You are using find_by without mentioning the column. Change it to `Question.find_by(id: params[:id])` or `Question.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: just change your find_by in find as @kiddorails already said

Comment: @kiddorails omg! You're absolutely right! I don't know how I missed that misunderstanding.. : (Thank you very much!

Comment: Hah, I totally couldn't spot that too. Hawk eye there, @kiddorails!

Comment: :) Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) without mentioning the *column*. When used without specifying column, `find_by` uses it as *WHERE* condition

Change it to `Question.find_by(id: params[:id])`(returns nil if matching record is not found) or `Question.find(params[:id])`(raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error if record not found).

Answer (score 1):

This is the clue.

> ```
> Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE (6) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
>   ↳ app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:86
> ```

This is generated from `@question = Question.find_by(params[:id])`. Note the `WHERE (6)`. [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) takes either a single argument of raw SQL to use in the `where` clause, or a column and a value. You've only given it a single argument, so it's interpreted it as SQL and thus `WHERE (6)`. This will be true for every column, so you get some random column, in this case 3, then you destroy it.

Instead you want:

```
@question = Question.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Or better, use [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

And if you're just going to destroy it, use [`destroy` on the class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-destroy).

```
Question.destroy(params[:id])
```